# Segmentation fault with Gtk console on 64-bit system

Tags: segmentation-fault, 32bit-64bit, gtk3, archlinux, red

I've compiled a Red console [with Gtk3 support](https://github.com/red/red/wiki/%5BNOTES%5D-Gtk-Bindings-Development). When I run View tests, such as included in repo `tests/react-test.red`, i get an error:

```
$ ./console tests/react-test.red

*** Runtime Error 32: segmentation fault
*** at: F6B4E33Eh
```

`ldd console` does not report missing libraries. The same binary works OK in 32-bit Debian.

What can be the problem?

When I add `system/view/debug?: yes` line to `tests/react-test.red`, there is some debugging info about *View* events before segfault error:

```
$ ./console tests/react-test.red
-- on-change event -- 
    face : window 
    word : type 
    old  : word 
    new  : word
-- on-change event -- 
    face : window 
    word : size 
    old  : none 
    new  : pair
-- on-change event -- 
    face : window 
    word : pane 
    old  : none 
    new  : block
-- on-change event -- 
    face : text 
    word : type 
    old  : word 
    new  : word
-- on-change event -- 
    face : text 
    word : size 
    old  : none 
    new  : pair
-- on-deep-change event -- 
    owner      : text 
    action     : set-path 
    word       : size 
    target type: pair! 
    new value  : none! 
    index      : -1 
    part       : -1 
    auto-sync? : true 
    forced?    : false
-- para on-change event -- 
    word : align 
    old  : none 
    new  : word
-- on-change event -- 
    face : text 
    word : size 
    old  : pair 
    new  : pair
-- on-change event -- 
    face : text 
    word : para 
    old  : none 
    new  : object
-- para on-change event -- 
    word : parent 
    old  : none 
    new  : block
-- on-change event -- 
    face : text 
    word : size 
    old  : pair 
    new  : pair
-- para on-change event -- 
    word : parent 
    old  : block 
    new  : none
-- on-change event -- 
    face : text 
    word : type 
    old  : word 
    new  : word
-- on-change event -- 
    face : text 
    word : size 
    old  : none 
    new  : pair
-- on-deep-change event -- 
    owner      : text 
    action     : set-path 
    word       : size 
    target type: pair! 
    new value  : none! 
    index      : -1 
    part       : -1 
    auto-sync? : true 
    forced?    : false
-- para on-change event -- 
    word : align 
    old  : none 
    new  : word
-- font on-change event -- 
    word : style 
    old  : none 
    new  : word
-- font on-change event -- 
    word : name 
    old  : none 
    new  : none
-- font on-change event -- 
    word : size 
    old  : none 
    new  : none
-- on-change event -- 
    face : text 
    word : size 
    old  : pair 
    new  : pair
-- on-change event -- 
    face : text 
    word : text 
    old  : none 
    new  : string
-- on-change event -- 
    face : text 
    word : para 
    old  : none 
    new  : object
-- para on-change event -- 
    word : parent 
    old  : none 
    new  : block
-- on-change event -- 
    face : text 
    word : font 
    old  : none 
    new  : object
-- font on-change event -- 
    word : parent 
    old  : none 
    new  : block

*** Runtime Error 32: segmentation fault
*** at: F6B5E33Eh
```

Comment: I don't know much about Red (*cough*), but I do know the GTK branch is experimental.  You should either raise this on [GitHub issues](https://github.com/red/red/issues), or in the [Gitter.IM chat](https://gitter.im/red/red).

Comment: After couple days of testing, it looks like the problem is limited to Arch Linux. It compiles and runs ok on Ubuntu & CentOS. Moreover, a binary compiled on Arch runs on other distros without problems.

Comment: Problem [has been fixed recently](https://github.com/red/red/commit/4f44ff9b4779654b1f619c402359336df80a4251). Now binaries built for Linux work properly under Arch.